# Write to XML for creation of reporting services file, trouble with quotes

Tags: c#, xml, reporting-services

I can't figure out how to modify the C# code below, which works as it is.

```
 writer.WriteElementString("Value", 
 "=Parameters!StartDate.Value + Parameters!EndDate.Value");
```

This results in the following in the XML file.

```
<Value>=Parameters!StartDate.Value + Parameters!EndDate.Value</Value>
```

I want to add the word "To", but I can't figure out how to do it given the required quotes when I write to xml.

I want the result to look like this:

```
<Value>=Parameters!StartDate.Value + " To " + Parameters!EndDate.Value</Value>
```

How do I modify the xml writer code listed above to get this result in the xml file?  I can't figure out how to arrange the quotes in the original code to achieve this result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes in your string literal, ie:

```
writer.WriteElementString("Value", "=Parameters!StartDate.Value + \" To \" Parameters!EndDate.Value");
```